# Playerprefs dont work fine!

Tags: unity, c#

because it don't work fine! i am pretty sure there is no else problem.
also how can i remove playerprefs data in windows? i used Playerprefs.Deleteall(); but it also don't work.
is there any problem with this code?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class s1sc : MonoBehaviour {
    int isfirsgamestart = 1;

    //load saved variable in playerprefs
    void Start(){
        isfirsgamestart = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("is player first game?");
    }

    //save variable in playerprefs
    public void _SetInt(){
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("is player first game?", isfirsgamestart);
    }

    //delete all playerprefs
    public void _delete(){
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to format your code into a good shape before posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(); Removes all keys and values from the preferences. Use with caution.

PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(); work correctly just it work when reset the game(because when reset game load again values)

```
//delete all playerprefs
public void _delete(){
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll ();
    Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

because it just remove keys and values from the preferences,this is mean it delete information so you need load them again

```
//delete all playerprefs
public void _delete(){
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll ();
    isfirsgamestart = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("is player first game?");
}
```

another ways:

```
public void _delete(){
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey ("is player first game?");//delete key
    isfirsgamestart = 0;//initialize again
    //________OR____________
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("is player first game?", 0);//set int to zero mean reset
}
```